# Highcharts how to pass data from server into chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

This is code from example [Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-column-null-values/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column',
                        margin: 75,
                        options3d: {
                            enabled: true,
                            alpha: 10,
                            beta: 25,
                            depth: 70
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: '@Model.FirstName'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            depth: 25
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: Highcharts.getOptions().lang.shortMonths
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Sales',
                        data: [2, 3, null, 4, 0, 5, 1, 4, 6, 3]
                    }],
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                });
            });
        });
```

I want to pass series "data: [2, 3, null, 4, 0, 5, 1, 4, 6, 3]" and categories: "Highcharts.getOptions().lang.shortMonths" from server. How can i do it?

Comment: What type of server? What type of website? PHP? .Net? Magic wishing? :)

Comment: Net. I just want to know how to get information from server via Highcharts.

Comment: That is only half the problem. Highcharts supports specifying a data source via a URL, but *you need to supply the data*. :)

Comment: Yes, how can I send request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request data via Ajax and call `chart.addSeries`

```
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myserverurl',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            chart.addSeries({
              name: "somename",
              data: data.mydata
            });
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```